# How do disable new "gray out errors" in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

Just recently, Visual Studio Code started "graying out" errors when they appeared in my code. If you don't know what I'm referring to, look here:

[image: example of grayed-out errors]

I would like to disable how Visual Studio Code does this, and return to the default syntax highlighting of everything, but still include the red underlining of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was documented in the [VS Code 1.24 release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_highlight-unused-variables-and-imports). The solution is to go to your user settings by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> and then add the following two lines:

```
"javascript.showUnused": false,
"typescript.showUnused": false
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't really have time to read over the release notes, but you just helped me out a lot.